# Sequelize.js model has manufacturedFrom and manufacturedTo properties. How to get all car models that were being manufactured during a specific year?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have the following Model/Table:

```
Table: models
Columns: name, manufacturedFrom, manufacturedTo
```

and some example records:

```
5 Series    2010    2017
6 Series    2011    2018
X4 (F26)    2014    2018
```

Now lets say I want to get all models that were being manufactured during year 2018. That means I'd get only these 2:

```
6 Series    2011    2018
X4 (F26)    2014    2018
```

Right now I'm getting all models like this:

```
let Model = require('../models/Model')

module.exports.getModels = async (req, res, next) => {

    let response = await Model.findAll()

    res.status(200).json({
        models: response
    })

}
```

The problem is that I can't quite figure out what kind of operators should I use to get those records. I tried some stuff with greater than and lesser than, but I wasn't quite successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Op.gte] and [Op.lte] like this:

```
const year = '2018';
let response = await Model.findAll({
  where: {
    manufacturedFrom: {
      [Op.lte]: year
    },
    manufacturedTo: {
      [Op.gte]: year
    }
  }
})
```